# Generate random number from $P(x)=Ax^{-3/2}\exp(-B/x)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, random

I wish to numerically generate a random number from the distribution
$$ P(x) = Ax^{-3/2}\exp(-B/x),\qquad A,B,x>0 $$

What would be the easiest way of achieving this?

---

[Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) does not seem appropriate since the above $P(x)$ does not have an analytical cumulative distribution function.

[Rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) requires a second distribution to draw samples from, but I don't know what known distribution would be efficient for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is distributed according to your density, then $\frac{2B}{X}$ has density proportional to $x^{-\tfrac{1}{2}} e^{-x/2}$. This is the density of a Chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom, i.e. $X \stackrel{d}{=} \frac{2B}{N^2}$, where $N$ is a standard normal random variable.

Comment: It works. Very neat solution, thanks.